# Angular 2 Access Service return data outside function

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-services, angular2-components

Here is my function  and service return json  List and i can list data in my HTML very well but the problem is how can i access this returned data out side function in type script

```
reloadFilms(params) {
    this.spinnerService.show();           
    this._productListService.getProductList().subscribe((productListData) => {
        this.filmResource.query(params)
            .then(films => this.films = productListData);
        this.spinnerService.hide();
        this.dtTrigger.next();
        });
}
```

i need to access this.films here

```
filmResource = new DataTableResource(this.films);
```

Comment: what's the error ? you just need to assign the value or something else?

Comment: Actually this is used in angular 5 data table and in demo they used films[data] as dummy constant and import constant and use it, i need to implement data from service , data getting very well , problem is initialize  DataTableResource need data as parameter 
so using subscriber data cant access out side method

Comment: can you produce your problem here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pgccbj?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: i just put code there but its difficult to produce entire code  
https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular5-data-table 
problem occur when  i implement data from service.
if you can please explain how to implement data table with any other option also acceptable

Comment: didn't able to find your code there, have you saved it after adding code ?

Comment: please check now , my intention is only implement  npmjs.com/package/angular5-data-table with service returned  data